# wordpress if ( have_posts() ) , loop not working

Tags: php, wordpress

just wondering can anyone see anything wrong with this code. It worked perfectly on the development version, and this is an exact copy.

I thought it may have been something within the loop but I even tried `echo 'hello';` straight after the `if ( have_posts () ) :` and nothing appeared, yet I did the same immediately before the `if` and it appeared.

Here is the overall code....

```
if ( have_posts() ) : 
            $the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'p' => 4998 ) ); /*  */
             while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
              the_content();
             endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();

                endif; 

            ?>
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT : Apologies if my problem sounded vague, basically whats not working is that nothing at all is appearing even though the post ID is correct and there is no other issues regarding css etc as to why it wouldnt appear. And even after trying to just display a word like "hello" after the `if` , still nothing.
Im just confused as to why this would stop working all of a sudden.
Thanks again.

Comment: well how are we supposed to know whats not working,

Comment: `can anyone see anything wrong with this code`? The indentation, for starters.

Comment: I think you need to get the query and check have_posts() on that have_posts() as a global checks if the page has_posts (complicated settings and stuffs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep I checked. Use have_posts() on the query you create (create query outside `if`)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

As a global call, have_posts() checks if the page, if configured the right way, has posts.

Comment: Thank you, I think I need to understand that particualr function a little better than I do obviously, I took it out and it worked perfectly. Cheers